# FFmpeg Concat Filter High Memory Usage

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using FFmpeg to join many short clips into a single long video using the `concat` filter. FFmpeg seems to load all clips into memory at once and quickly runs out of RAM (For 100 clips it eats over 32GB). Is there a way to limit the memory used by the concat filter?

The command I would use for 3 inputs is as follows:

```
ffmpeg -i 0.mp4 -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v][0:a][1:v][1:a][2:v][2:a]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1" out.mp4
```

It seems to use around 200MB per additional input, which quickly uses all the memory in my system.

Comment: Share full command and log.